# How can I install Lustre file system on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, cluster-computing

I am newbie to Lustre File system and I wish to install it on Ubuntu 12.10, there is no information on the Lustre website to do so.

Is it possible and how would I install Lustre in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

[Lustre](http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a transparent global file system , the client can transparently access the cluster file system data , without having to know the actual storage location of the data . The client through the network to read data on the server , storage server is responsible for the actual file system read and write operations. The Lustre file as positioned by the metadata server object metadata server guide the actual file I / O requests to the storage server, storage server management in object-based physical storage on the disk group .

As a result of metadata and store data phase separation technique can be fully separated computing and storage resources , so that the client computer can focus on user and application requests .

**There are a lot lustre articles  , but rarely about the article on ubuntu** , as lustre compiler installation is really enough trouble , but as long as understand, it is nothing more difficult the !

```
mds: 192.168.6.6
ost1: 192.168.6.119
ost2: 192.168.6.137
client: 192.168.6.137 because the resource problem, I put in ost2 client machines operate.
```

One in mds [kernel](http://www.kernel.org) [download linux-2.6.22 kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.22.tar.gz) , because lustre-1.6.5 supports up to linux-2.6.22

```
apt-get install quilt linux-patch-lustre libncurses5-dev module-assistant dpatch lustre-utils
shell $> cd / usr / src
shell $> ls
kernel-patches linux-2.6.22.tar.bz2
shell $> tar jxvf linux-2.6.22.tar.bz2
shell $> cd linux-2.6.22
shell $> ln-s / usr/src/kernel-patches/lustre/series/2.6.22-vanilla.series series
shell $> ln-s / usr / src / kernel-patches / lustre / patches / patches
shell $> quilt setup series-d patches
# Patch for the kernel to fight lustre
shell $> quilt push-av
shell $> quilt refresh
shell $> make clean
shell $> make mrproper
shell $> cp / boot/config-2.6.27.7-server. config
shell $> make menuconfig
# Compile the kernel , I believe we all know what they need , and here I will use the default does not make any changes !
shell $> make-kpkg - added-patches = lustre - initrd - append-to-version "-lustre" - revisionn ludy.1 kernel_image
# version and revision followed by the version number !
shell $> dpkg-i linux-image-2.6.22-lustre_2.6.22-lustre-ludy.1_amd64.deb
shell $> reboot
# From the start after the selection of the newly compiled kernel
shell $> uname-r
2.6.22-lustre
shell $> m-a auto-install lustre
# Install kernel module containing lustre
# After a long wait finally finished compiling !
```

The lustre-modules-2.6.22-lustre_1.6.5_amd64.deb linux-image-2.6.22-lustre_2.6.22-lustre-ludy.1_amd64.deb copied to the client machine with two ost have chosen to install the kernel 2.6.22 into the system !

To Test:

**1.** Modify three servers / etc / hosts

```
192.168.6.6 mds
192.168.6.119 ost
192.168.6.137 cls
```

**2.** In md server performs the following actions

```
modprobe lustre
modprobe ldiskfs
modprobe lnet 'network = "tcp0 (eth0)"'
mkfs.lustre - reformat - fsname = testfs - mdt - mgs / dev/sda5
# If the hard disk is not formatted , or there are data , then need to add - reformat parameter formatting !
mkdir-p / opt / mds
mount-t lustre / dev/sda5 / opt / mds
```

**3.** Do the following actions on the two ost

```
modprobe lustre
modprobe ldiskfs
modprobe lnet 'network = "tcp0 (eth0)"'
mkfs.lustre - fsname = testfs - ost - mgsnode = mds @ tcp0 / dev/sdb1
# Similarly, if sdb1 is not formatted or the data must be added - reformat parameters
mount-t lustre / dev/sdb1 / opt
```

**4.** In the client server implementation ( ie ost2)

```
mount-t lustre mds @ tcp0 :/ testfs / mnt
Good three servers have even made it !
We have a large file tests to establish
```

**5.** In the client server implementation

```
 dd if = / dev / zero of = test1 bs = 1024 count = 40000
    40000 +0 records in
    40000 +0 records out
    40960000 bytes (41 MB) copied, 2.85257 s, 14.4 MB / s
```

In ost1 server performs df-lh View

```
/ dev/sdb1 1004M 57M 897M 6% / opt
```

In ost2 server performs df-lh View

```
/ dev/sdb1 1004M 17M 897M 2% / opt
```

Obviously ost1 written 40M of data ost2 now
In the second execution

```
dd if = / dev / zero of = test2 bs = 1024 count = 40000
40000 +0 records in
40000 +0 records out
40960000 bytes (41 MB) copied, 4.66784 s, 8.8 MB / s
```

In ost1 server performs df-lh View

```
/ dev/sdb1 1004M 57M 897M 6% / opt
```

No change
In ost2 server performs df-lh View

```
/ dev/sdb1 1004M 57M 897M 6% / opt
ost2 data is written to the 40M !
```

**6.** Stop lustre file system

```
umount-f / opt
```

I did a little simple explanation for lustre works !

mds is probably a place to store the metadata file list is the same thing , he knew the files stored on the server in which Taiwan ost
ost file is stored in the server

I just can not study lustre accurate to say anything. Experts hope a lot of advice !

**Note:** After the start mds ost skip mkfs.lustre not newly created file system
Need only mount-t lustre hanging in the file system can be !
This help comes from ["linuxer" blog](http://deidara.blog.51cto.com/400447/125071)

You can also try this for lustre client ubuntu...[here](http://build.whamcloud.com/job/lustre-master/arch=x86_64,build_type=client,distro=ubuntu1004,ib_stack=inkernel/)..